# Online solving for nash equilibrium with imperfect knowledge of actions

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

For simplicity sake, let's say $M$ is a two player, constant sum game. This gives us uniqueness of NE payoffs and 'interchangeability' of strategies.

We can solve for Nash equilibrium using linear programming methods, or use a suitable adversarial bandit algorithm for each player's selection policy over a number of rounds and finally take the empirical strategies as an approximation.

Suppose though our game is very large, and we do not have knowledge of either players action space. In fact, this problem is formulated over $t$ rounds and every round we observe a new action for each player. I don't currently know what to assume about this process though (e.g. is it stochastic over each action space?)

Is there any work on solving games in this context? What about similar scenarios?
Currently I'm using exp3 as a bandit algorithm, and when a new team is introduced, it is assigned a logit score that is the median of the highest and lowest scores. So a new action is $r$ times more likely to be selected than the least likely, and $r$ times less likely to be selected than the most likely.Actions are pruned if their selection prob is less than $\frac{c}{k \ln{k}}$ where $k$ is the number of actions. This is a request for papers and comments.

Comment: You are missing a lot of details about your problem. Is the action space finite or infinite? Are you assuming that you are an external agent watching people play and you want to learn a NE or are you trying to design an algorithm from a player's perspective to reach a NE? If you are designing an algorithm for an agent what assumptions do you have on the knowledge they have. Do they know their cost function? Do they know the outcomes from pure strategies if the action space is finite? Do they only know the outcome of just the actions played?

Comment: The matrix is finite. My problem arises from self play, so there is one external agent with both 'players' knowledge. Realize now my wording in the OP suggests otherwise

Comment: It's still not clear what is the problem. Does the external agent see the outcomes for each player as well? If so over time you will get to see the outcomes and corresponding actions for all the agents (assuming that there is some probability of selecting any action in their action set). You will know everything about the game and can use any of the methods you mentioned above to get the NE.

Comment: The external agent can see the reward for both players. The information in this problem is about as libre as imagine. Still I'm not convinced of the last sentence. I am trying to find an $\epsilon$-NE of a very large matrix game, where only a small subset of the actions can fit it memory. Not much is known about this game, other than that there exists $\epsilon$-NEs whose supports *can* fit into memory.

Comment: Also I only withheld this information out of fear of over specificity, but my game is also symmetric, and I am specifically using this fact as well as the 2 player constant sum game to consider only one strategy/bandit algo at a time